# Dimension of Intersection of Algebraic Sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

In Mumford's *Red Book* (Remark III on page 21) he gives the following construction:

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $X=V(xw-yz)\subset k^4$ and $U=D_X(y)\cup D_X(w)$. Define $h\in\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$ by setting $h=\frac{x}{y}$ on $D_X(y)$ and $h=\frac{z}{w}$ on $D_X(w)$.
>
> Suppose that $h$ is of the form $\frac{f}{g}$ on $U$. Then let $Z=V(y,w)$, this is a plane in $X$ and $U=X\setminus Z$. We have that $V(g)\cap X\subset Z$ by assumption, and **all components of $V(g)\cap X$ have dimension $2$**.

I'm struggling to justify the statement in bold. He refers us to Chapter 7, but I can't find a result which explains it. His Corollary 3 there seems to say that if $W$ were a component of $V(h)$ viewed as a closed subset of $X$, then $\text{codim}(W)\leq1$ and so $\dim(W)\geq3$, but this can't be the case since it is contained in a plane.

I know that for irreducible affine algebraic sets $A,B\subset k^n$ we have, for any component $W$ of $A\cap B$, that $\dim(W)\geq\dim(A)+\dim(B)-n$. Then since $\dim(X)=4$, if I could show that $\dim(V(g))=2$ I think we would be done since $\dim(V(g)\cap X)\leq\dim(Z)=2$ because $V(g)\cap X\subset Z$. However I can't see why $V(g)$ needs to be irreducible, or how to show its dimension is $2$ even if it is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. What I know is that if $X$ is any irreducible algebraic set (like $V(xw-yz)$, which is actually normal) and $f \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_{X})$ is not zero or a unit, then $V(f)$ has pure codimension $1$ in $X$. More generally, this holds true for any integral $k$-scheme of finite type.

Comment: The dimension of $V(xw-yz)$ is $3$ and not $4$. You imposed a set of non-trivial conditions on $k^4$, so the dimension has to drop by at least $1$. More formally, it follows from the fact I stated above.

Comment: Many thanks for clearing that up, I'm not sure why I thought $\dim(X)$ was $4$ now in retrospect, but I understand the argument now, thanks again